# Python: Translate csv dataframe

Tags: python, csv, dataframe

I have a [.csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx9mdGvx6TsZbDdKeThLUklMX0k/view?usp=sharing) file looks like:

```
> "referrers":[{"id":"m.facebook.com","label":"m.facebook.com","count":466},{"id":"www.facebook.com","label":"www.facebook.com","count":102}],"countries":[{"id":"US","label":"United
> States","count":4},{"id":"AE","label":"United Arab
> Emirates","count":2},{"id":"MY","label":"Malaysia","count":1}]
```

and I want transfer to a data table:

```
id    | m.facebook.com | www.facebook.com | US            | AE | MY
---------------------------------------------------------------------
label | m.facebook.com | www.facebook.com | United States | ...
---------------------------------------------------------------------
count |       466      |        102       |      4        | ...
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please read the [help] pages to see what sort of questions are allowed here.

Comment: Your file looks like JSON.

Comment: Second the JSON. It certainly doesn't look like any kind of CSV I've ever seen.